# divergence operator on an oriented Riemannian manifold does not depend on the choice of oritetation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was doing exerice in Lee's smooth manifold book,in page 423 needs to show that divergence operator on Riemannian manifold is independent of orientation ,and it's invariantly defined on all Riemannian manifold.

My attempt,if the manifold is connected ,we know there exact two orientation on $M$,if the orientation are different,then we know $dV_g = -d\tilde{V}_g$ (where they are Riemannian volumn form on $M$ with different orientation.) .

Hence we see $$\text{div}X  = \star_\mathcal{O}^{-1}d(i_X(dV_g)) = -\star_\mathcal{\tilde{O}}^{-1}d(i_X(-d\tilde{V_g})) = (-1)\cdot(-1) \star_\mathcal{\tilde{O}}^{-1}d(i_X(d\tilde{V_g}))$$

that is to say different orientation has same expression for divergence.

Hence we have proved it's independent of choice of orientation on connected manifold.

There are two questions here:

1. I stuck in the step that for general case.Do we need to use the fact that $\text{div}$ is local operator?
2. Does invariantly defined means under different Riemannian metric $g$ and $\tilde{g}$ the $\text{div}X$ has same expression?

---

Edit:

**Step 2**(disconnected case)

We first prove the following lemma (Before proving the theorem we need to assume that $div$ depend on the orientation)

> **lemma** Let M be an oriented Riemannian manifold, pick any point $p$ and neiborhood on $p$  denote it $U$(treated as oriented submanifold of $M$ with induced orientation $\mathcal{O}|_U$).Then we have $$\text{div}_{(M,\mathcal{O})}X = \text{div}_{(U,\mathcal{O}|_U)} X|_U$$ for all $p\in U$   (where $\text{div}_{M,\mathcal{O}}X$ is the divergence operator defined on manifold $M$ with orientable $\mathcal{O}$)

If we can prove this,then for disconnected manifold,we can pick a connected neiborhood $U$ around point $p\in M$ then we have $$\text{div}_{(M,\mathcal{O})}X _p = (\text{div}_{(U,\mathcal{O}|_U)}X|_U) _p = (\text{div}_{(U,\mathcal{\tilde{O}}|_U)}X|_U) _p = \text{div}_{(M,\tilde{\mathcal{O}})}X _p$$ holds for all $p \in U$

Hence we have prove the disconnected case

**Step 3**(non orientable case)

Due to local piece of Riemannian manifold is always orientable,which means for any $p\in M$ exist some neiborhood of $p$ that $U_p$ is an oriented submanifold.Hence we can define the $\text{div} X$ at $p$ be the divergence of $X$ inside this small pices $U$ that is define LHS as : $$ (\text{div} X)_p = (\text{div}_U X|_U)_p$$ for each $p \in U$

(The local definition on arbitary Riemannian manifold(including the non-orientable case) consistent with the original definition due to the lemma above.)

Comment: It's not clear what invariant means here..... definitely not the one you mentioned in 2. May be they mean they can define it also on a non-orientable Riemannian manifold?

Comment: I was trying to prove it independent of metric $g$ but find it depends on $g$.Due to the extrieror derivative. I guess "define it also on a non-orientable Riemannian manifold"  is the correct interpretation thank you.